# dropdown to pull from mysql

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a MySQL database that has 4 tables: customer, products, orders & order_details.
I am trying to get a form (html or php) that has drop downs:
1-customer : pulls from customer table
2-Item: pull sfrom products table
3-Category: pulls from products table

then post the information into order & order_details.
I got the form to pull the data from a view but i need it to post the data.\

here is the code:

```
<?php
include ('connect.php');    
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Company FROM `values` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select Company='Company'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Company'] ."'>" . $row['Company'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Item, Type FROM `values` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select Item='Item'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Item'] ."'>" . $row['Item'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM `values` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select Type='Type'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['Type'] ."'>" . $row['Type'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
<input type="Submit">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you not mention about the structure of you table. 
lets you have your company table like(or make it)

```
company table
+--------+-----------+-------------------+
| id     |  company  | some other field  |
+--------+-----------+-------------------+
| 1      | abc       | xxxx              |
+--------+-----------+-------------------+
| 2      | def       | xxxx              |
+--------+-----------+-------------------+
```

//id should be  primary key

```
your product table (each product is made by some company)
+--------+-----------+-------------------+
| id     |  product  | company_id        |
+--------+-----------+-------------------+
| 1      | p1        | 2                 |
+--------+-----------+-------------------+
| 2      | p2        | 1                 |
+--------+-----------+-------------------+
```

now you can do like

```
//code to show list of companies

 $sql = "SELECT `id`, `company`  FROM  `company` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select Company='Company'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] ."'>" . $row['Company'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

`Edit:`

Great, now your dropdown shows the compay list. 
But i think you missed the `<form action='' method = "POST">` in your question or may be in your file.
make a full functional form.

```
<?php
    //change according to your settings 
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db("st") or die(mysql_error());


?>
    <form action="st2.php" method = "POST">
        <label for="company_id">Compay</label>
        <select name="company_id" id="company_id">
            <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT `id`, `company`  FROM  `company` LIMIT 0, 30 ";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] ."'>" . $row['company'] ."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>

        <label for="product_id">Product</label>
        <select name="product_id" id="product_id">
            <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT `id`, `product`  FROM  `product` LIMIT 0, 30 ";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] ."'>" . $row['product'] ."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>

        <label for="category_id">Category</label>
        <select name="category_id" id="category_id">
            <?php 
                $sql = "SELECT `id`, `category`  FROM  `category` LIMIT 0, 30 ";
                $result=mysql_query($sql);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] ."'>" . $row['category'] ."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name = "Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Lets your orders table have structure like this

```
+--------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| id     |  company_id  | product_id  | category_id  |
+--------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| 1      |    1         | 2           |  8           |
+--------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

again here id is primary key and 
company_id = id in company table, product_id and category_id are also id's of their tables which are unique for that table

=> make a file save.php and process the data send by your form here

```
<?php
    //change according to your settings 
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db("st") or die(mysql_error());


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    var_dump($_POST);
    $company_id = $_POST['company_id'];
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];

    //Note: sanitize and validate data before saving in database 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO orders VALUES('', $company_id, $product_id, $category_id)";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if($result) {
        echo "data saved";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }

}?>
```

//read more about input fields in html, PDO class of php, data sanitization and validation and sql queries.

**problems : updated:**
when i run your code. i was confused about some of your field. what are you trying to do with this form. what i understand
`1` a customer can add a order. but then why there is a dropdown to choose customer and actually you are displaying company with customer label.

`2` some input field -
**order**-> user provide a order name or order_id  if order_id then it is not good for db. bcoz a user can make same order id twice.
**date**-> what date, completion or current date of submission, if current date then you should done in in back end.
**checkbox** ->why check box not getting
**blank and ship**-> what they are
**Tax** -> user give the tax on product, its ok (may be i am wrong)
**price** -> user give price per product ,ok  ( may be i am wrong)
**total** -> user give total, or it should be calculated as price * quantity + total tax. then there is no need of input box

make it more clear before implementing what info. you want to get from a user and it is safe or not. or you generate that for user. because forms comment user to db which can cause serious problems.

Comment: Ok, the dropdown displays the values but still didn't post to the table.
knowing that the dropdown pulls from one table(company) and posts to another table(order).

Comment: GREAT !! works perfect. You are a genius, thanks. I need to do couple more things. this form posts to 2 tables : orders & order_detail. Orders has Order_id as auto increment. Order_details has Trans_id as auto iuncrement & Order_id as int . I want the order_id that just gbot incremented in Orders to copy itself into Order_details. Also I need to be able to "add Row" in the the form columns: Quantity|Product|Category|Price|tax

Comment: thanks. it is not difficult now. but do it first> `1-` your order_id of orders table is = id of orders table that i made(does the same job and both are auto increment). `2-` I think price is stored along with product in products table. add a new column in products table(price). `3-` tax is fixed (as i think) or you can add a new column in products table to store tax. do it . i will update my answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<label for="company_id">Company:</label>
<select name="company_id" id="company_id">
    <option value="0">-- Select Company--</option>
    <?php 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='{$row[company_id']}'";
            if ($errors && $_POST["company_id"] == $row[company_id']) {
                echo 'selected="selected"';
            } 
            echo ">{$row['company_name']}</option>";
        } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried it with Company_id the drop down came empty. then I tried this:
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Company FROM `customer` LIMIT 0, 30 "; $result=mysql_query($sql); echo "<select Company='Company'>"; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo "<option value='{$row['Company']}'"; if ($errors && $_POST["Company"] == $row['Company']) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } echo ">{$row['Company']}</option>"; } echo "</select>"; 
It didn't post? is that valid?

Comment: What does your table look like? I asume it's company_id / Company (name) ?

Comment: I updated my answer. You may have to change company_id to the ID name you use, and company_Name to the name you use in your table...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my form:

```
<?php

//change according to your settings 

 include ('connect.php'); 

mysql_select_db("hachemal_compuworld") or die(mysql_error());

?>

<form action="Add_order.php" method = "POST">

&nbsp;<label for="Customer">Customer<br />
</label>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="Cust_id" id="Cust_id" style="width: 126px">

        <?php 

            $sql = "SELECT `Cust_id`, `Company`  FROM  `customer` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                echo "<option value='" . $row['Cust_id'] ."'>" . $row['Company'] ."</option>";

            }

        ?>

</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

Order:&nbsp; <input name="Order_id" type="text" style="width: 52px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Status&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" id="txtDate" onclick="fnPopUpCalendar(txtDate,txtDate,'mm/dd/yyyy')" style="width: 72px" name="Date"/>&nbsp;
<span class="style2">..&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<SELECT name="Status" style="width: 78px; height: 22px">

                <OPTION value="Open" selected="">Open</OPTION>

                <OPTION value="In Progress">In Progress</OPTION>

                <OPTION value="Paid">Paid</OPTION>

                <OPTION value="Past Due">Past Due</OPTION>

                <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>

                <option value="Closed">Closed</option>

            </SELECT>...............</span>&nbsp;<br>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;



    <br>



<TABLE id="dataTable0" width="350px" cellspacing="1" class="style5">

    <TR>

        <TD style="height: 32px" class="style1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;</TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px" class="style1">&nbsp;</TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px" class="style1">&nbsp;</TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px" class="style1"><span class="style2">.. .</span>Qty<span class="style2">...</span></TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px" class="style1">

            <span class="style2">.......</span>Product<span class="style2">........</span></TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px" class="style1">

            <span class="style2">....</span>Category<span class="style2">....&nbsp;

            </span>

        </TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px" class="style1">

            <span class="style2"></span>blank<span class="style2"></span>&nbsp;

        </TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px" class="style1">

            <span class="style2">.</span>Price<span class="style2">.</span></TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px" class="style1">

            <span class="style2">...</span>Ship<span class="style2">..</span></TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px" class="style1">

            <span class="style2">..</span>Tax<span class="style2">...</span></TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px" class="style1">

                            <span class="style2">..</span>Total<span class="style2">...



</TABLE>



<TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" cellspacing="1" class="style5">

    <TR><TD style="height: 32px"><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>



                    <TD style="height: 32px"></TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px"></TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px">



        <INPUT type="text" name="Qty" style="width: 37px"/></TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px">



       <select name="Product" id="Product" style="width: 87px">

        <?php 

            $sql = "SELECT `Product`, `Product`  FROM  `Products` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                echo "<option value='" . $row['Product'] ."'>" . $row['Product'] ."</option>";

            }

        ?>

    </select>

<TD style="height: 32px">





<select name="Category" id="Category" style="width: 89px">

        <?php 

            $sql = "SELECT `Category`, `Category`  FROM  `Products` LIMIT 0, 30 ";

            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                echo "<option value='" . $row['Category'] ."'>" . $row['Category'] ."</option>";

            }

        ?>

    </select>



</TD>







        </TD style="height: 32px">

    </TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px">

            <input name="Text2" type="text" style="width: 37px"></TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px">

            <input name="Price" type="text" style="width: 39px"></TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px">

            <input name="Ship" type="text" style="width: 42px"></TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px">

            <input name="Tax" type="text" style="width: 39px"></TD>

        </TD style="height: 32px">

            &nbsp;</TD>

        <TD style="height: 32px">

            <input name="Total" type="text" style="width: 50px"></TD>

    </TR>

</TABLE>



<br>



    <input type="submit" name = "Submit"/>

</form>









<br>



</html>
```

Comment: it is totally mixed up. i am working on it. can you please paste your each table structure from phpMyAdmin > database > table> structure

Comment: like products( id-auto_increment, product, price,tax,...)

Comment: this is Orders table:
Order_id int(11)   No None AUTO_INCREMENT
Date text latin1_swedish_ci
Cust_id int(11)  
Trans_id int(11) 
Total decimal(10,0)
Status text latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: this is Order_details table:
1  Trans_id int(11)   No None AUTO_INCREMENT 
  2  Order_id int(11)   
  3  Qty int(11)   Yes NULL
  
  4  Product varchar(60) 
  
  5  Category varchar(30) 
 6  Price decimal(10,2)   
  
  7  Ship decimal(10,2)
  8  Tax decimal(10,2)   
  9  Total decimal(10,2)

Comment: this is my first database , so excuse the mess:)
I appreciate your help

Comment: ok no problem if it is your first db. we definitely make it work.

Comment: this form is for me to generate invoice to a customer.
Date: calendar popup to input order date=current date
Order_id= auto generate/auto increment-i would like to see if possible post in both Orders table & order_details table

checkbox ->to be used to select a row & delete 
blank:ignore
ship-> I show details & shipping per row
Tax -> i show tax per row
price ->price for a product
total: calculates total (quantity* price +ship+tax)

Comment: still missing (upper customer dropdown with company information).

Comment: now you mean when a customer arrive on that page the date,his id,etc remain same(only once) and then he has some rows of product(so he can select what he want) and you only want to print tax,price,ship charge of that product(not a input field).

Comment: can we chat? it would be quicker.

Comment: this form is NOT for the customer. this is on my end.
I generate this form as invoice and I send to them.
All they see is the output